# mysql: get value of table row in bash

Tags: mysql

When I run this command I get a full table output....

```
mysql --user=root --password="mypassword" -e "SELECT btce_last_price FROM api.btc WHERE id=1"


+-----------------+
| btce_last_price |
+-----------------+
|             723 |
+-----------------+
```

I would like the output to be just "723".

Comment: Try adding `--skip-column-names`

Comment: This gives me.                                                        +-----+
| 723 |
+-----+

Comment: SOLVED adding "-s  --skip-column-names"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the [silent mode](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-command-options.html#option_mysql_silent) `-s` to produce less output. You can also add [raw](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-command-options.html#option_mysql_raw) `-r` and `--skip-column-names`

Comment: -s helps....I had to add grep to ignore tablename... mysql --user=root --password="mypassword" -e "SELECT btce_last_price FROM api.btc WHERE id=1" -s |grep -v btce_last_price.

Comment: or adding "head -1" to remove first line output.

Comment: SOLVED... "-s  --skip-column-names"

Answer (score 1):

The `-N` switch removes column names and you can use awk to strip the tabular formatting (whitespace, pipe & dash symbols):

```
SQL='SELECT btce_last_price FROM api.btc WHERE id=1'
mysql -u root -p "mypassword" -N -e "$SQL"|awk '{print $1}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
mysql --user=root --password="mypassword" -e "SELECT btce_last_price FROM api.btc WHERE id=1" | tr -dc '[0-9]'
```

That'll get you your bitcoin prices by pulling out only the numbers from that output.

If you aren't just looking for numbers, you can use

```
mysql --user=root --password="mypassword" --skip-column-names -e "SELECT btce_last_price FROM api.btc WHERE id=1"  | tr -d '[\+\-\| ]'
```

As long as there aren't and +, -, | or spaces in your value... otherwise you have to get trickier.

Comment: This works but not all values are numbers. How about if the value is "abc4329480_+908902"

Comment: This works for my requirements at this time. But I thought it should be easier to get any value. I tried to +1 but don't have enough rep yet.